# browser shows the html code for "return View(object)"

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

We have a page in asp.net MVC 4 (razor view). When we run the page in browser, it shows the html code instead of the design. The action method looks like the following,

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ChangePassword(ChangePasswordUI changePasswordUI)
    {
            //Validate the current password
            //add error to the model
            ModelState.AddModelError("CurrentPassword", "Invalid current password");
            return View(changePasswordUI);
     }
```

The output is like this

[image]

The response in the firebug looks below

[image]

Comment: You got this issue on production server or visual studio development server?

Comment: visual studio development server.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that's very weird. Looks like a browser problem. Could you install [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) and look at the `Net` tab? More specifically the `Content-Type` response header. If it is `test/html` then you definitely have a problem with your browser. Maybe some plugin is preventing from properly displaying the HTML. You may also try another browser.

---

UPDATE:

OK, now that you have shown the screenshot from FireBug it is clear what the problem is. The response Content-Type header is set to `application/json`. The ViewResult that you are using should set the `Content-Type` header to `text/html`. So I guess you have some other part of your code which is overriding this setting and using `application/json`. It could be an action filter or something else. Hard to tell without knowing your code.

Comment: I have attached the Firebug response in the question. The content-type shows it is json but I'm returning just a view.

Comment: OK, now it's clear what the problem is. The `Content-Type` is set to `application/json` instead of `text/html`. You probably have some code that is overriding the default content type for a view which is `text/html`. So you must fix this.